Can I suppress rule CS9035 once?
I have an Options class like this (note the required keyword):
public class Options
{
    [Required]
    public required string Endpoint { get; set; }
}

It is loaded from the configuration like this:
public static IServiceCollection AddOptions(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection section)
{
    var options = new Options();
    section.Bind(options);
    ....
}

The constructor line now makes the compiler complain:

Error CS9035: Required member 'Options.Endpoint' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor.

Since I know that .Bind() below (in combination with the [Required] attribute and settings validation (not shown here)) will make sure that all properties of Options are properly set, I want to disable the compiler warning.
Unfortunately, adding #pragma warning disable CS9035 has no effect.
I know, I can initialize the required Endpoint member in the constructor like this, but that does not feel good and looks awkward:
var openAIOptions = new OpenAIOptions { Endpoint = null! }

What other options do I have?

I think CS9035 is an error, not a warning and therefore you cannot simply disable it in a trivial way.

Why did you add the required keyword?

I have nullable enabled. Using required I do not need to explicitly set EndPoint in the constructor. What is more, if I had a constructor with EndPoint as parameter, I'd need to define the default constructor, too, which is required for deserialization. But then I'd need to prevent programmers from using that default ctor somehow.

So the purpose of adding required is to avoid writing constructors, but you should know that this does not remove your obligation to initialize this property.

You might want to separate the options into two types, one which is for general consumption where the property is guaranteed non-null, and a DTO which is used with the Bind() and then is validated and converted to the general-use type.

Instead of Bind use Get<T>
var options = section.Get<Options>()


you could a constructor in your class where you set Endpoint to null together with the SetsRequiredMembers attribute:
[SetsRequiredMembers]
public Options()
{
    Endpoint = null!;
}

